# Como plotar coordenadas negativas (polo Sul) usando ggmap, ggplot?

Tags: ggplot2, r

Estou tentando plotar uns pontos entre América do Sul e a Península Antártica, mas da erro quando faço a delimitação da área que desejo apareça no mapa `(xlim, ylim)`.

Já tinha plotado o mapa sem problema, mas agora está dando erro.

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-80, -48.12), ylim = c(-50, -68), expand = FALSE)

Error in st_normalize.sfc(x, c(x_range[1], y_range[1], x_range[2], y_range[2])) : 
  domain must have a positive range
```

O que poderia estar acontecendo e como resolver o problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está nas coordenadas de `ylim`. Inverta a ordem delas e tudo se resolverá. Olha o Estreito de Drake ali embaixo, como deveria ser.

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-80, -48.12), ylim = c(-68, -50), expand = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcus, pequeno detalhe que não enxerguei.

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.